# Make stretch imageview in gridview

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, imageview

the image in my gridview isn't stretch.

how can I stretch it?

This is mine.

[image]

This is what i want

[image]

Gridview

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_base"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <com.camitss.mcolle.ScrollableGridView
                android:id="@+id/grid_all"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:columnWidth="110dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
                android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

GridView Item

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/card_base"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- Green Image -->
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/category_card"
    android:layout_width="105dp"
    android:layout_height="105dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

<!-- Picture -->
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="95dp"
    android:layout_height="95dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

Comment: set image Length and Height = fill parent, instead "xxdp"

Comment: it isn't work. I test it already. :D

Comment: Let me give a try!! just share the source images

Comment: @RDC you want my source image?

Comment: yeah the Green background and the foreground image

Comment: @RDC It's working now. I Try answer Appu below. thanks for helping me

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21935/discussion-between-rdc-and-kongkea)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
<!-- Picture -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="95dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
```